# Cannot stop deprecated warning in PHP

Tags: php, jenkins, testlink

I seem to be hitting the problem described in this blog titled [PHP 5.6: “Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.”](https://www.bram.us/2014/10/26/php-5-6-automatically-populating-http_raw_post_data-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-a-future-version/).  As can be seen in this output of ngrep on my server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK..Date: Mon, 09 Mar 2015 20:28:06 GMT..Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/1.0.0j DAV/2 PHP/5.6.2..Content-Length: 819..
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100..Connection: Keep-Alive..Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8....<br />.<b>Deprecated</b>:  Automatically populating
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini
and use the php://input stream instead. in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />.<br />.<b>Warning</b>:  Cannot modify header information - headers
already sent in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />.<?xml version="1.0"?>.<methodResponse>.  <params>.    <param>.      <value>.
<array><data>.  <value><struct>.  <member><name>code</name><value><int>2000</int></value></member>.  <member><name>message</name><value><string>
(check  DevKey) - Can not authenticate client: invalid developer key</string></value></member>.</struct></value>.</data></array>.   </value>.
</param>.  </params>.</methodResponse>.
```

This message is what is being returned to Jenkins TestLink Plugin when it attempts to communicate to TestLink via XML-RPC.   You can see clearly that the deprecated warning is preceding the XML response, which in turn causes the "modify header information" issue.

But, what I don't get is that I can't seem to suppress this warning.  If I set `always_populate_raw_post_data = -1` it seems to have no effect.  I thought perhaps I was editing the wrong php.ini file, but I followed the suggestion [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/466622/php-ini-changes-dont-have-any-effect) and was able to verify that changes I make are being picked up by the server.  My only theory is that TestLink is overriding these values in the application but I can't seem to find anything related in my installation.

EDIT:
Some Environment Info: Apache 2.2.15-39 on port 80, with PHP 5.6.6-1 and TestLink 1.9.13 using MySQL 5.1.73.
Jenkins 1.601 on Tomcat 8.0.20 running on port 8089.

If I look closely at the message above I see `PHP/5.6.2`, yet if I do a find on my system `find / -type f -name php` I get only `/usr/bin/php`...

Comment: Did you restart the web server after setting it to -1?

Comment: Thanks.  Yes.  I can see changes appear in my phpinfo script, so php is picking them up.  But strangely, ignoring some values, for instance I have been unsuccessful in get errors to appear in a log file when I set error_log to /tmp/php_errors.log ...  if I run php at command line errors will go into that file, but not those from scripts run on the server.

Comment: I read the blog post, that looks like a very annoying situation. Can you add `ob_start();` to your script to try to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I learned a lot, while digging into this, but as it turned out my mistake was quite simple.  I had copied the XML-RPC URL from some documentation into the configuration of the Jenkins Testlink Plugin, and forgot to edit it to be the URL for my server.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set error_reporting to E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED which should prevent displaying notices about deprecation.
This may be applied in php.ini or in build configuration in Jenkins.

Comment: Tried that in php.ini, with no luck.  Can you explain how to change it in jenkins build?

Comment: If You suspect that something is changing Your error reporting values You can always do this from within code: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED);`
I don't know how exactly Jenkins is building Your application so It's hard to advice where to put it in Jenkins build.